# MySQL- Misuse of aggregate function

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have been trying to run the following command:

```
select s.name, s.nr
from sub s
group by s.name
having (select count(s.name) from sub s group by s.name) > 
10 * (select avg(count(s.name)) from sub s group by s.name)
```

in order to get the name and phone number of all subscribers who have made more than 10 times the average number of calls per subscriber.

What am I doing wrong in the `select avg(count(s.name)) from sub s group by s.name` ?

Comment: Can you add some sample and expected data? Or could you just provide the sample data on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: The avg() subquery returns an average per s.name, not the overall average of counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
select s.name, s.nr
from sub s
group by s.name, s.nr
having count(*) > 10 * (
    select avg(cnt)
    from (
        select count(*) as cnt
        from sub
        group by name, nr
     )x
```

You can also get the average count with a single (not nested) subquery:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct name, nr) from sub
```

Read it as: *number of all rows / number of distinct groups* - Which is the average number of rows per group.

So your full query would be:

```
select s.name, s.nr
from sub s
group by s.name, s.nr
having count(*) > 10 * (select count(*) / count(distinct name, nr) from sub)
```